# Why does $y=\frac{4x-1}{(x^2+3)^{1/3}}$ have all real numbers?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

$$
y=\frac{4x-1}{(x^2+3)^{1/3}}
$$

I don't understand why it goes from negative infinity to positive infinity.

Comment: What exactly "geos from negative infinity to positive infinity? Are you trying to find the domain of the function?

Comment: It seems as though he is asking why there are no gaps in the domain

Comment: It could be understood as the question why the *range* of it is the whole $\mathbb R$, i.e. why it is "onto".

Answer (score 6):

The denominator is bounded below by $\sqrt[3]3$, so never goes to zero, so the domain is all real numbers.  When $x$ is very large in absolute value the $-1$ and $+3$ do not matter much, so we have approximately $y \sim x^{1/3}$.  This clearly goes from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$, so the range is all real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution(s) to $x^2 + 3 = 0$ are complex numbers.